# Reading JSON with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I've got the following JSON feed:

```
{
  collection_name: "My First Collection",
  username: "Alias",
  collection: {
     1: {
        photo_id: 1,
        owner: "Some Owner",
        title: "Lightening McQueen",
        url: "http://hesp.suroot.com/elliot/muzei/public/images/randomhash1.jpg"
        },
     2: {
        photo_id: 2,
        owner: "Awesome Painter",
        title: "Orange Plane",
        url: "http://hesp.suroot.com/elliot/muzei/public/images/randomhash2.jpg"
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is get the contents of the collection - photo_id, owner, title and URL.  I have the following code, however I am getting GSON JSON errors:

```
   @GET("/elliot/muzei/public/collection/{collection}")
    PhotosResponse getPhotos(@Path("collection") String collectionID);

    static class PhotosResponse {
        List<Photo> collection;
    }

    static class Photo {
        int photo_id;
        String title;
        String owner;
        String url;
    }
}
```

I thought my code was correct to get the JSON feed, however I'm not so sure.  Any help appreciated.

The error I get is:

```
Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 75
```

However I'm struggling to understand how to use the GSON library

Comment: What sort of error are you receiving? Logcat please?

Comment: Basically, the key line is:  Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 75

Comment: okay, so I'm not incredibly familiar with gson, but it seems like it was expecting an array of `Photos` rather than a `List` of them.

Comment: @K20GH Was this the actual JSON you are parsing? I don't think so because `Column 75` would be the in the middle of the first `photo_id`.

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON is not valid.

GSON is waiting for a `BEGIN_ARRAY "["` after `collection:` because your `PhotosResponse` class define an array of Photo `List<Photo>` but found a `BEGIN_OBJECT "{"`, it should be

```
{
    "collection_name": "My First Collection",
    "username": "Alias",
    "collection": [
        {
            "photo_id": 1,
            "owner": "Some Owner",
            "title": "Lightening McQueen",
            "url": "http://hesp.suroot.com/elliot/muzei/public/images/randomhash1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "photo_id": 2,
            "owner": "Awesome Painter",
            "title": "Orange Plane",
            "url": "http://hesp.suroot.com/elliot/muzei/public/images/randomhash2.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

maybe you get that JSON from an incorrect `json_encode()` PHP array with key, you should encode JSON from PHP without keys, with the array values only ([PHP Array to JSON Array using json_encode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722059/php-array-to-json-array-using-json-encode))

Comment: Right, looks like that it should be `collection: [`. But, I'm still curious if his code will work.

Comment: @user1923613 What are you curious about?

Comment: @JoshPinter, I think how Retrofit GSON could get "collection" key-values pairs directly without being bothered by "colllection_name" and "username". I am running into the same error. I have to write my own GSON adapter to get it right, similar to this[link]( http://sachinpatil.com/blog/2012/07/03/gson/)