# GSON is trying to deserialize a String to double

Tags: json, string, double, gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit with a GSON converter to obtain JSON from a RESTful Web Service and when GSON tries to convert a JSON object to POJO I'm getting the error:

> retrofit.Converter:conversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "610/182"

This element corresponds to a String variable in my Java Object:

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("code")
private String code;
...
```

And the JSON Object is:

`{"code":"610/182", ...}`

I added a converter to my `RestAdapter` like this:

```
    restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL_BASE)
            .setClient(new OkClient(getClient()))
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();

    api = restAdapter.create(ApiRest.class);
```

Why GSON is trying to convert a String into a double?

Comment: Can you post hte full code that is doing the conversion.  Other questions have syntax errors elsewhere that cause this type of thing. like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887318/reading-json-with-retrofit

Comment: post the complete class. Make sure there is no other `
@SerializedName("code")`

Comment: Have you fixed this problem what was the reason of this error?