# php json_encode single item numeric array

Tags: php, arrays, json

When I do `json_encode` from this array:

```
array('aps' => array(
                     'alert' => array(
                                     'param1'=>array('string'), 
                                     'param2'=>'string' )));
```

I'm getting this JSON object:

```
{
    "aps" :    {
      "alert" :         {
            "param1" :             {
                "0" : "string"
            },
            "param2" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
{
    "aps" :    {
      "alert" :         {
            "param1" :             
                ["string"],

            "param2" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work right when the `param1` array is not a single item. 
How could I fix it? The Json is created from a third party bundle, so I should format the array in PHP so that I could get the correct JSON on `json_encode` (`param1` as a list).

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: What's wrong with it apart from the missing quotes, which are really beside the point?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran - I don't want the `0` index from the single numeric array (`param1`)

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](http://3v4l.org/6TYcm). I suspect you rewrote your code and output for the question—you should post some *real* code we can test.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas: Your expected output is what you should be getting, and indeed [what I am getting](http://ideone.com/xomVST).

Comment: @Jon - It's really strange...

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - Now it is right, but I don't understand why I'm not getting that JSON.

Comment: Sorry but what you claim to be your actual JSON does not even pass the [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) validator. I'm sure you honestly think you've posted the relevant code but facts suggest is isn't the case.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - Yes, sorry. I was missing a coma. I think now it is right.

Comment: No, it isn't. The problem is that you are typing manually some code that you wrongly think that illustrates the issue. You should be using the clipboard to post **real code** that you've tested yourself.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - Sorry, validated and edited.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11722121/1466341

And more info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

> **Note:** When encoding an array, if the keys are not a continuous numeric
>   sequence starting from 0, all keys are encoded as strings, and
>   specified explicitly for each key-value pair.

In your case everything should work fine, but I guess you have simplified your PHP array in this example. So, idea is simple - if your PHP array don't have all keys sequential, then json_encode will treat them as keys of object.

Comment: I knew that. But I supposed that if there is only one key, it is treating it as an associative one. But I think that I was wrong with it.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. Maybe that depends on your PHP version.