# PHP convert Array to JSON issue?

Tags: php, arrays, json

When I `print_r($arr)` something like `Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => world);` is output.

I tried to convert in **JSON** string using below code.

```
$result['result'] = $arr;
json_encode($result);
```

This results in this JSON string:

```
{"result" : { "0" : "hello" , "1" : "world"}}
```

The expected result would be this:

```
{ "result" : ["hello" , "world"]}
```

What can I do to get the desired output?

Comment: Is that really your code? Where does the array come from? The second result looks like the one you would get.

Comment: I want format like `{ "result" : ["hello" , "world"]}` ... but not get. Yupe it's mine code

Comment: check this link both show same output 

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: `print_r($arr)` Output looks like `Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => world);`

Comment: Yes, with $arr = array("Hello", "world"); you would get your wanted result, so show your $arr ;)

Comment: Simply you can't basically json also returns an array so to access an array you have to use it's indexes as well.

Comment: solution which -RST has marked is perfect.

Comment: @AmitShah thanks. Any reason why you duplicated it after your comment?

Comment: @RST, i was just drafting answer, and adding it to question, i found you have already added. Ultimately the goal should be questions should get resolved :).

Comment: go through below link, hope it will resolve your problem

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722059/php-array-to-json-array-using-json-encode/49988572?noredirect=1#comment93544485_49988572

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result['result'] = array_values($arr);
json_encode($result);
```

use the values only.

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty simple, please use code given below.

```
$arr = array("0"=>'hello',"1"=>'world');
$result['result'] = array_values($arr);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Need to do like this:

```
$result['result'] = array_values($arr);
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => world); -> if that's really the output he got, than $arr isn't an object, it's an array ;)

Comment: ok its my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

put your array values to the result key of array. then it will print the required result.

```
$arr = array("0"=>'one',"1"=>'two');
$result['result'] = array_values($arr);
echo json_encode($result);
```

online demo http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4227f1bbeb675c6950d9e4e0f189477153dff3e