# incorporate json object into datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I have json data that's being imported to a page where I am trying to create a datatable.

the `console.log(jsonReturn)`:

```
 {"1":{"dateReceived":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.7200","number":"757991"},"2":{"dateReceived":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.7200","number":"757991"}}
```

Below is my var `jsonReturn`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [dateReceived] => 1905-07-04            
            [cost] => 2.7200
            [number] => 757991

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dateReceived] => 1905-07-04
            [cost] => 2.7200
            [number] => 757991

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [dateReceived] => 1905-07-04
            [cost] => 2.7200
            [number] => 757991

        )

)
```

I've read through every example on the DataTables website and I can't find anything on how to utilize this variable to fill my table.  Apart from initializing the table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var table = $('#ltc-table').dataTable( {
    "aaData" : jsonReturn,   
});
```

Setting `aaData` to `jsonReturn` loads something into my table, but it's just gibberish.  I need to know how to tell DataTables exactly where to find the data I want it to use to populate the table, and which rows I want to display where, etc.

I arrive at this javascript var by doing the following:

The user searches with a text-box, which goes off to an ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'quoteManagerSearch.php',      
      data: {searchBy:searchBy, searchValue:searchValue, options:options},        
        success:function(data){                
        jsonReturn = data;
        $("#quoteReturn").load("return.php");
        //$("#quoteReturn").html(data);                                            
        }
  }); //close ajax call


$searchQuery  = "SELECT * FROM alldata where $searchBy like '%$searchValue%'" ;
$searchResult = mysqli_query($con, $searchQuery);

$x = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($searchResult)) {

$x = $x + 1;


    $output[$x]["dateReceived"] = convertDate($row[1]);
    $output[$x]["cost"] = $row[15];
    $output[$x]["number"] = $row[16];
    }


echo json_encode($output);
```

on success, `return.php` is loaded into a div, and `var jsonReturn` is created.

Then, in `return.php` I try to use my invalid object.

## Update

In response to @davidkonrad's post:

I'm getting the following error now:

```
DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed.  This is caused by a JSON formatting error.
```

From what I can see (minus the quotation marks,) my JSON string looks exactly like yours.

```
{"aaData":[ 
  {"dateReceived":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.7200","number":"757991"},
  {"dateReceived":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.9200","number":"337995"}
  ]
}
```

I also changed `DataTable` to `dataTable` since I'm using 1.9.4 for this test.

## Update #2

**I figured out what's going wrong!**

The process, as I saw it, is as follows:

1. User loads quoteManager.php, and enters options in a textbox, then hits `search`.  This value is converted into a javascript var, and sent off in this ajax call:

   ```
   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'quoteManagerSearch.php',      
   data: {searchBy:searchBy, searchValue:searchValue, options:options},        
     success:function(data){                
     jsonReturn = data;
     $("#quoteReturn").load("quoteManagerReturn.php");
     }
   ```

   }); //close ajax call
2. quoteManagerSearch.php is the actual query against the database.  This outputs a valid JSON string.

in `quoteManager.php`, there is a `<div>` at the bottom of the page for this response to load into:

```
<div id="quoteReturn">
</div>
```

3. I do something wrong here.
4. `quoteManagerReturn.php` is loaded into the `#quoteReturn` div on the `quoteManager.php` page - but without any of the data that `quoteManagerSearch.php` returned, because `quoteManagerReturn.php` is running its own ajax to `quoteManagerSearch.php` - not using the one I ran in the beginning, and this string, `$searchBy = $_POST['searchBy'];` is empty - so I get no results.  This is why it's telling me my JSON is invalid, because it's empty!
5. What I need to do (which I'm not sure how to do...)

   1. Use `jsonReturn` in `quoteManagerReturn.php` - as this is the valid JSON response I want, instead of making a **new** ajax request to `quoteManagerSearch.php`, or
   2. Pass these variables over from `quoteManager.php` to `quoteManagerReturn.php`and send them in the ajax request I'm making from `quoteManagerReturn.php` to `quoteManagerSearch.php`.

## Update 2++

I sorted this out by just adding the variables into my ajax call on the second page:

```
var table = $('#ltc-table').DataTable( {    
      ajax : { 
       url : 'quoteManagerSearch.php' ,       
       dataSrc : 'aaData' ,
       type : 'POST',
       data: {searchBy:searchBy, searchValue:searchValue, options:options},
      },
```

I've taken the original ajax call out of my first page (since there's no reason for the duplication...) **I believe this is the solution!**

Comment: Can you post exactly what the jsonReturn variable shows if you console log that variable in javascript?

Comment: k, original post updated with that

Comment: The datatable takes an array I believe. The json you have is not a javascript array.

Comment: The JavaScript was created from a PHP `while` loop that grabbed data out of a table, then took that array and did `json_encode($array);` - so I'm not sure where I would have gone wrong....

Comment: to get the correct format from php, check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722059/php-array-to-json-array-using-json-encode

Comment: latest versions of datatables use Datatable function uppercase instead of lowercase

Comment: What version of dataTables? 1.9.x or 1.10.x?

Comment: The JSON in your updated question is valid JSON and works with dataTables 1.10.7 and 1.9.4 as well.  You mention quotation, there _must_ be quotation around fieldnames.   Are there any extra in the JSON?

Comment: The JSON that I posted in my original question is exactly what was output on the screen - I was relating to the first block of code text in your comment, where there are no quotation marks around `aaData` , etc.  It looks to me like my JSON is perfect, but I'm still getting the same error (1.9.4 or 1.10.7)...

Comment: Interestingly enough, when i run this through the datatables debugger, under "Server Interaction", I get this as the `Last JSON from Server`.   `< br / > < b > Warning < /b>:  mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\ltc\quoteManagerSearch.php</b > on line < b > 24 < /b><br / > {
    "aaData": []
}`  I'm not sure if this is just an error in the debugger, as in Chrome's debugger I clearly see the proper JSON response being output by `quoteManagerSearch.php`

Comment: figured this out - see original post, I've updated with the actual problem! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using dataTables 1.9.4 or similar, based on the reference to `aaData`. dataTables 1.9.x wants a JSON response that looks like

```
{ aaData : [ 
   { item }, 
   { item }, 
   ...
  ]
}
```

So in order to get the right format of the JSON, change the last part of your quoteManagerSearch.php script to this :

```php
...
$output = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($searchResult)) {
    //create { item }
    $item = array();
    $item["dateReceived"] = convertDate($row[1]);
    $item["cost"] = $row[15];
    $item["number"] = $row[16];
    //add { item } to [] 
    $output[] = $item;
}
//add [] array to aaData
$result = array('aaData' => $output);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Now you can initialise the dataTable and define "which values to read and where to put them" :

```js
var table = $('#ltc-table').dataTable( {
    sAjaxSource : 'quoteManagerSearch.php',
    aoColumns : [
        { mDataProp : 'dateReceived' },
        { mDataProp : 'cost' },
        { mDataProp : 'number' }
    ]
});
```

---

As for dataTables 1.10.7, I would say that the above initialization would work well too. I tried it out with no errors. dataTables maps option names and so on in pairs with the old hungarian notation names and the new API naming standard, and even `aaData` works as default, even though dataTables now first looks for a `data` object. If you want to make the code fully "1.10.7 compliant" do this instead :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ajax : {
        url: 'quoteManagerSearch.php',
        dataSrc: 'aaData',
    },
    columns : [
        { data : 'dateReceived' },
        { data : 'cost' },
        { data : 'number' }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks David, I really appreciate your help here.  I'm using DataTables 1.10.7.  How does the above code change if I move up to 1.10x?

Comment: I've updated my main post with a more properly-formatted response.  I also switched to 1.9.4 to test this answer out, but I still cannot get a JSON format that datatables likes.

Comment: @JohnWu, see update - I believe you just can use the above code in 1.10.7 too, but have updated the answer. No need for changing the PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

your json is a javascript object with numbered properties:

```
{
  "1":{"dateReceived":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.7200","number":"757991"},
  "2":{"dateReceived":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.7200","number":"757991"}
}
```

should be an array of javascript objects like this:

```
[
  {"dateReceived":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.7200","number":"757991"},
  {"dateReceived":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.7200","number":"757991"}
]
```

Comment: To help get the correct format in php check this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722059/php-array-to-json-array-using-json-encode

Comment: Okay - my string now looks the same as what @tellez suggested. [{"dateReceived":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.7200","number":"757991"},{"dateReceived‌​":"1905-07-04","cost":"2.7200","number":"757991"}] . Still though - I don't know how to tell DataTables which values to read, and where to put them.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're pulling data from a server side REST API,
usually in newer versions of datatables you would do something like:

```
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    "language": language,               
                    "ajax": {
                        "url" : "/myservice/rest/" + params,
                        "error": function(reason) {
                            $('#myTable').html(errorMessage);
                            }
                        }
                    },
"columns": [
                    {"data": "orderNum"},
                    {"data": "orderDate"},
                    {"data": "customerName"},
// other column samples ...
                ],
    // other params ...
    });
```

Comment: I definitely integrate with several RESTful APIs, so I'll save this for sure.  Thank you!