# How to covert Laravel's collection to array object collection?

Tags: laravel

I have small laravel collection as below.

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
   data1: 11,
   data2: 12,
   data3: 13,
   created_at: null,
   updated_at: null
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   data1: 14,
   data2: 15,
   data3: 16,
   created_at: null,
   updated_at: null
 }
]
```

But I would like to convert to array collection like below.

```
{
 data: [
   [
     11,
     12,
     13
   ],
   [
     14,
     15,
     16
   ]
 ]
}
```

Appreciated for advice and so sorry for my English. Thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried toArray()?

Comment: Dear Collin, Appreciated much for some guidance, Thanks.

Comment: maybe refer to https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: Hope This will Help You !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849481/converting-an-array-of-arrays-from-laravels-collection-into-an-object-with-an-a

Comment: Dear Saengdaet, Thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: Dear  Abir Adak, Thank for link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toArray()` which converts this object into an array.

```
$data->toArray();
```

Now the collection converted into an array and looks like:-

```
[
 [
  id: 1,
   data1: 11,
   data2: 12,
   data3: 13,
   created_at: null,
   updated_at: null
 ],
 [
   id: 2,
   data1: 14,
   data2: 15,
   data3: 16,
   created_at: null,
   updated_at: null
 ]
]
```

But as per your requirements, you don't want associative index for the array, So use

```
$data = array_values($data);
```

Now your keys has been removed and final data is:-

```
[
   [
     11,
     12,
     13
   ],
   [
     14,
     15,
     16
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: Dear Sahil Gupta, Actually it need to add prefix 'data: '.

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution Simply use $data['data'] = array_values($data);