# Convert JSON response to Array format in Android

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am getting response from server in JSONArray format. I am not able to retrieve the contents of array also my JSONArray has no Square brackets.

I am passing the response in php as `json_encode($array)` in server side

```
response {
     community = “worker”
     communitystr = "<null>";
     workspace = abs;
     email = "<null>";
     admin = false;
     persona = "<null>";
     userinfo =  {
     info =   {
        contact1 =    {
            firstname = “jon”;
            lastname  = “Doe”
            phone = “9885678905”;

            objectname = contact;
            id = 9;
        };
        event1 =      {
            eventname = “party”;
            description = "";
            order = 6;
            id = 4;
            objectname = events;
        };
        files =       {
            filename = “sample”;
            description = "";
            order = 11;
            id = 11;
            objectname = files;

         };
      };
   };
};
```

I checked many links and all have used `JSONObject()`. But same is not working for me.

How do I get each values in this JSON Response ?

Comment: `Invalid JSON `

Comment: your json is invalid , check response at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya , It is invalid because it has no square brackets ' [ ' ?

Comment: @AnitaAlvekodi yes

Comment: also there is no problem in parsing this in iOS , isn't there a way to parse it in android ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 
: instead of =
, instead of ;

...

Watch out following format:

```
        {
          "Herausgeber": "Xema",
          "Nummer": "1234-5678-9012-3456",
          "Deckung": 2e+6,
          "Waehrung": "EURO",
          "Inhaber": 
          {
            "Name": "Mustermann",
            "Vorname": "Max",
            "maennlich": true,
            "Hobbys": [ "Reiten", "Golfen", "Lesen" ],
            "Alter": 42,
            "Kinder": [],
            "Partner": null
          }
        }
```

Your code seems like to be more JavaScript-Object like :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not valid JSON object.

You can validate the JSON via some online tool, like http://jsonlint.com/

Full specification can be found in RFC 7159 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.

Basically you should look how to encode the values into JSON format in correct way. For that you can refer to [PHP Array to JSON Array using json_encode();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722059/php-array-to-json-array-using-json-encode)