# Delete array in JSON file with PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Hi I'm looking how to delete a array in json file based on the ID value.

Here is my json file

```
[
    {
        date: "3/7/2017",
        title: "kjjnkjnjn",
        category: "Automobile",
        ville: "Labas",
        decription: "nlknlknklnkjlnkl",
        mail: "mathieufrobert@yahoo.fr",
        telephone: "0777878988",
        pseudo: "kknklnkln",
        prix: "10",
        mdp: "0000",
        id: "5959785fde3bc26610"
    },
    {
        date: "3/7/2017",
        title: "kjjnkjnjn",
        category: "Automobile",
        ville: "Labas",
        decription: "nlknlknklnkjlnkl",
        mail: "mathieufrobert@yahoo.fr",
        telephone: "0777878988",
        pseudo: "kknklnkln",
        prix: "10",
        mdp: "0000",
        id: "6848675fde3bc26610"
    },{
        date: "3/7/2017",
        title: "kjjnkjnjn",
        category: "Automobile",
        ville: "Labas",
        decription: "nlknlknklnkjlnkl",
        mail: "mathieufrobert@yahoo.fr",
        telephone: "0777878988",
        pseudo: "kknklnkln",
        prix: "10",
        mdp: "0000",
        id: "5737554fde3bc26610"
    }
]
```

Here is my php file (it's a copy from another php)

```
<?php
$file = $_POST["id"];

$animals = file_get_contents('text.json');

$animals = json_decode($animals, true);
foreach ($animals as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($file, $value)) {
        unset($animals[$key]);
    }
}
$animals = json_encode($animals);
?>
```

And my Ajax code

```
$("#5959785fde3bc26610").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "delete.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: "5959785fde3bc26610",
        },
        success: function (result) {
            Materialize.toast('Annonce Supprimé!', 4000);
        }
    });
});
```

This is how I'd like my json file to look like

```
[
    {
        date: "3/7/2017",
        title: "kjjnkjnjn",
        category: "Automobile",
        ville: "Labas",
        decription: "nlknlknklnkjlnkl",
        mail: "mathieufrobert@yahoo.fr",
        telephone: "0777878988",
        pseudo: "kknklnkln",
        prix: "10",
        mdp: "0000",
        id: "6848675fde3bc26610"
    },{
        date: "3/7/2017",
        title: "kjjnkjnjn",
        category: "Automobile",
        ville: "Labas",
        decription: "nlknlknklnkjlnkl",
        mail: "mathieufrobert@yahoo.fr",
        telephone: "0777878988",
        pseudo: "kknklnkln",
        prix: "10",
        mdp: "0000",
        id: "5737554fde3bc26610"
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance for you're help.

Comment: which part of the code you need help? the php part or javascript ?

Comment: Javascript and PHP because it just doesn't work I may be missing something

Comment: if that is the exact json in your file, i would say the first step would be formating it to have a right json format . eg : date, title. mail should be wrapped with double quote. You can check the validation of your json here
[json formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Your JSON File is NOT VALID JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would read the JSON in PHP, like this:

```
<?php

$id   = $_POST['id'];

// stop if it's non-numeric
if (!preg_match('/^\d+$/', $id)) {
  die('Don’t hack us.');
}

$file = 'the.json';
$data = file_get_contents($file);
$list = json_decode($data);

// now, we will search the ID
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {

  // if we found it,
  if ($list[$i]->id === $id) {
    // we remove it
    unset($list[$i]);
    break;
  }
}

// make the numeric array consecutive again
$list = array_values($list);

// write the resulting JSON to disk
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($list));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me =)
How can I remove the count in front of the other array when it's deleted ?

Thanks

Comment: Which count do you mean?

Comment: My file is like this :
[{"date":"2017, 07, 01","title":"zeezerzrez"},{"date":"2017, 07, 03","title":"zeezerzrez"}]
But after I use you're code my file look like this :
[1:{"date":"2017, 07, 01","title":"zeezerzrez"},2:{"date":"2017, 07, 03","title":"zeezerzrez"}]
There is a number in front and I can't use foreach code in ajax get

Comment: I have amended my code to fix this. See the line commented with `// make the numeric array consecutive again`. The reason is documented in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722059/php-array-to-json-array-using-json-encode

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you use ES6 Array.prototype.filter.

```
const deletePropWithId = (array, id) => {
  return array.filter((obj) => obj.id[id] !== undefined);
}
```

Comment: Could you be more precise where this piece of code should go ?