# PHP - How to modify the category_name and subcategory_name in array of object?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, foreach

Look my existing code:

```
class CategoryController extends ApiController
{
    public function getCategory(){
       $categories = DB::table('products')
        ->select('category', 'category_name')
        ->distinct('category', 'category_name')
        ->get();
        $newArr = [];
        foreach ($categories as $value) {
            $newArr[$value->category_name] = [];
            $subcategories = DB::table('products')
            ->select('subcategory_name')
            ->where('subcategory', 'LIKE', '%'. $value->category.'%')
            ->distinct('subcategory')
            ->get()->pluck('subcategory_name');
            array_push($newArr[$value->category_name], $subcategories);
        }
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $newArr
    ]);
    }

}
```

The response seems:

```
 "data": {
        "Food": [
            [
                "Chicken",
                "Egg",
                "Pie"
            ]
        ],
        "Drinks": [
            [
                "Beer",
                "Juice",
                "Water"
            ]
        ],
```

But this is not response what I want. I need like a:

```
data: {
{
category_name : "Food",
subcategories_name : ["Chicken", "Eggs", "Pie"]
}
{
category_name : "Drinks",
subcategories_name : ["Beer", "Juice", "Water"]
}
}
```

if you do not understand some part of the code ask me. I have fields in the products table like a category,  category_name, subcategory, subcategory_name. The code category and subcategory it belongs to are the same code. All I need is to write a response as I wrote above. my logic was to put all categories into categories and in subcategories, I set up all subcategories and then merge them into one array. It does not matter to me how it will look like this, only the result is important. Thank.

ps. I do not know how important my database is for you, but there is a table of products and 4 fields = category, subcategory, category_name, subcategory_name. This is all.

Comment: You should really learn to use JOINs.

Comment: how would this look like with joins?

Comment: It supposed to be just a hint. Didn't really want to elaborate :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to manually assign keys in your output array.

```
foreach ($categories as $value) {

        $subcategories = DB::table('products')
        ->select('subcategory_name')
        ->where('subcategory', 'LIKE', '%'. $value->category.'%')
        ->distinct('subcategory')
        ->get()->pluck('subcategory_name');

        $newArr[] = [
             'category_name' => $value->category_name;
             'subcategories_name' => subcategories;
         ];
    }

    $newArrValues = array_values($newArr);
    $output = json_encode($out);
```

Comment: Okey my response is now like a:

    "data": {
        "0": {
            "category_name": "Food",
            "subcategories_name": [
                "Chicken",
                "Eggs",
            ]
        },
        "1": {
            "category_name": "Drinks",
            "subcategories_name": [
                "Beer",
                "Water",
            ]
        },

Can remove this index 0: and 1 ... ?

Comment: Remove the first line in the loop.

Comment: it happens cause `$newArr` is indexed array. I think you can try to get values from array and then encode it to json. I'll update the answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722059/php-array-to-json-array-using-json-encode

Comment: @devnullΨ Thank you.