# How to output proper JSON array of objects from php for axios call

Tags: php, arrays, reactjs, object

I am making an api call to an api built by not me, the response is an array of objects but it actually a string, so i can't do anything with it

i tried tinkering with the php file but i've never done anything with it so i have no idea

```
try {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array('partnumber'));
    $stmt->execute();
    $array = $stmt->fetchALL();
    sort($array);

//make Json file
    echo '[';
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        $last = ($key !== count($array) - 1) ? "} , " : " }]";
        echo '{partnumber: "' . $row['partnumber'] . '", ';
        echo 'image: "/media/pic/' . $row['partnumber'] . '.jpg", ';
        echo 'retailPrice: "' . $row['retail'] . '", ';
        echo 'use: "' . $row['use'] . '"';
        echo $last;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

expectation:

```
 [{
    partnumber: "12355",
    image: "/media/pic/111112W BN.jpg",
    retailPrice: "20.00",
    use: "living"
    },
    {
    partnumber: "125556665",
    image: "/media/pic/111112W WBZ.jpg",
    retailPrice: "20.00",
    use: "laundry, living"
    },
    {
    partnumber: "12355666666",
    image: "/media/pic/111122 BK.jpg",
    retailPrice: "0.00",
    use: "bedroom, closet, entry"
    },
    {
    partnumber: "1233333333",
    image: "/media/pic/111122 BN.jpg",
    retailPrice: "0.00",
    use: "bedroom, closet, entry, hall, laundry, living"
    }]
```

result:

```
"[{partnumber: "10A19M60WCL", image: "/media/pic/10A19M60WCL.jpg", retailPrice: "0.00", use: "&"} , {partnumber: "10L27A19M8W", image: "/media/pic/10L27A19M8W.jpg", retailPrice: "0.00", use: "&"} , {partnumber: "10L27A19M8WD", image: "/media/pic/10L27A19M8WD.jpg", retailPrice: "0.00", use: "&"} , {partnumber: "10L27B11C5W", image: "/media/pic/10L27B11C5W.jpg", retailPrice: "0.00", use: "&"} , {partnumber: "10L27ST19M6W", image: "/media/pic/10L27ST19M6W.jpg", retailPrice: "0.00", use: "&"} , {partnumber: "10L30GU104W", image: "/media/pic/10L30GU104W.jpg", retailPrice: "0.00", use: "&"} , {partnumber: "111112W BN", image: "/media/pic/111112W BN.jpg", retailPrice: "20.00", use: "bedroom, closet, entry, hall, laundry, living"} , {partnumber: "111112W WBZ", image: "/media/pic/111112W WBZ.jpg", retailPrice: "20.00", use: "bedroom, closet, entry, hall, laundry, living"}]"
```

Comment: For JSON - your field names need to be in quotes as well [{"partnumber": "10A19M60WCL".  You should also use `json_encode()` to build the JSON as doing it manually may introduce coding problems.

Comment: yes im bringing this array into state for a react app, is the json method front end?

Comment: @nigelRen ok, done that, but the array is still surrounded by quotes :(

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722059/php-array-to-json-array-using-json-encode.

Comment: i didn't write this php file, i've never touched php but i have access to the file, so it looks like chinese to me @NigelRen im not connecting the dots

Answer (score 0):

turns out the database had line-breaks in it causing the JSON to become invalid
fixed by removing the line-breaks