# How to group subsequent rows (based on a criteria) and then count them [MySQL]?

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

Let's say I have such a table (ordered by date):

```
id | name | type  | date 
 1 | A    | 1     | 01-08-2012
 2 | A    | 2     | 01-08-2012
 3 | B    | 1     | 02-09-2012
 4 | A    | 1     | 01-10-2012
 5 | A    | 4     | 01-10-2012
 6 | A    | 5     | 02-10-2012
```

I want to group subsequent rows that have the same 'name' value and count them:

```
name | count 
A    | 2
B    | 1
A    | 3
```

I was thinking about writing a stored procedure and using cursors, but I was also wondering, if there's a simpler solution, for example using nested SELECTs, etc.

My question is very similar to: [how to group array and count them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255281/how-to-group-array-and-count-them), but that one concerns PHP.

Comment: what is the difference between `A | 2` and `A | 3`?

Comment: "A | 2" means that there are 2 subsequent rows with 'name' set to "A", "A | 3" means that there are 3 subsequent rows with 'name' set to "A"; between them there is one row with name = "B".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that I used a couple of variables,
the table structure, I created my own just for testing and it's:

```
create table abc (id int, name varchar(20),type int);

insert into abc values 
( 1 , 'A'    , 1  ),
( 2 , 'A'    , 2 ),
( 3 , 'B'    , 1  ),
( 4 , 'A'    , 1  ),
( 5 , 'A'    , 4  ),
( 6 , 'A'    , 5  )
```

the query ended being like this:

```
set @a:='';
set @counter:=1;
set @groupby:=0;
select *,count(REPEATED) from (select name,if(@a=name,@counter:=@counter+1,@counter:=1) as rep,if(@counter=1,@groupby:=@groupby+1,@groupby) as repeated,@a:=name type from abc) as t group by repeated
```

you can see it works in [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61395/95) if you have any question let me know.

In the SQLFIDDLE

Comment: I like it and now I have a new view for my problem, but your solution gives wrong answer: the query says that B is 2 times and doesn't keep the order of 'name', so, even if the B's count was correct, I don't know which A is which.

Comment: I figured out, that a problem is with GROUP BY. It orders 'groups inside' in such a way, that the row with rep = 1 goes first in each group.

Comment: please try it again let me know

Comment: Oh, now works:). But I've just tried exactly the same way and have failed. I must have been mistaken something.