# Selecting from a single date column and creating multiple start and end records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I really wanted to solve this problem but there comes a point when you have to just put it out there, learn and move on.

I have a temporary table which contains 1 column, POCDates, which is a list of dates, some of which are continuous/contiguous. For example:

```
POCDates
01/01/2014
02/01/2014
03/01/2014
04/01/2014
10/03/2014
11/03/2014
25/03/2014
26/03/2014
28/03/2014
```

I am looking to run a query in my procedure that will select from this temporary table and, using the sample data above, display the following:

```
POCDatesSummary
Start        End         Count
01/01/2014   04/01/2014  4
10/03/2014   11/03/2014  2
25/03/2014   26/03/2014  2
28/03/2014   28/03/2014  1
```

The count isn't essential, but I suspect that this is the most simple part using a DATEDIFF so I've left it in there.

I have tried a number of approaches and trawled forums for similar problems; nothing has come close. Hope I can find the answer here.

Comment: maybe this will help you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566303/how-to-group-subsequent-rows-based-on-a-criteria-and-then-count-them-mysql

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? That can make the answer simpler. And you want to group the days into continuous ranges?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 (I've updated the tag). Simply put, yes, when a group of days are continuous, I require them to be grouped as a range in some way or form, ideally presented as the example outcome in the post so further analysis can be conducted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursive CTE:

```
;WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT  POCDates, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY POCDates) AS RowNumber
    FROM    MyTable
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT  POCDates,
            POCDates AS RangeStart,
            POCDates AS RangeEnd,
            RowNumber
    FROM    cte1
    WHERE   RowNumber = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      c1.POCDates,
                CASE
                    WHEN c1.POCDates = DATEADD(day,1,c2.POCDates) THEN c2.RangeStart
                    ELSE c1.POCDates
                END             AS RangeStart,
                c1.POCDates     AS RangeEnd,
                c1.RowNumber
    FROM        cte2 c2
    INNER JOIN  cte1 c1 ON c1.RowNumber = c2.RowNumber + 1
) 

SELECT  RangeStart          AS [Start],
        MAX(RangeEnd)       AS [End],
        COUNT(RangeStart)   AS [Count]
FROM    cte2
GROUP BY RangeStart
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

`MAXRECURSION 0` allows the CTE to recur infinitely. The default value is 10, which will cause the query to fail if your table has more than 10 rows.

Comment: Impressive level of abstract thinking here, thank you for taking the time to write this. A few more tests to see if it stands up to rigour but all seems well so far. Forza!