# Counting Array Sub-Elements

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following multi-dimensional array:

```
Student Name Exam Result Exam Grade
David 79 1H
Brian 54 2H2
Lisa 55 2H2
Simone 58 2H2
Francis 78 1H
Shauna 53 2H2
Sean 40 Pass
Xavier 95 1H
Tom 60 2H1
Andy 66 2H2
```

And I need to come up with write a function to count how many times each 
particular grade was achieved within the exam. For example 3 "1H's" were achieved.  Any ideas?

```
$exam = array ( "names"  => array (  "David",
                                     "Brian",
                                     "Lisa",
                                     "Simone",
                                     "Francis",
                                     "Shauna",
                                     "Sean",
                                     "Xavier",
                                     "Tom",
                                       "Andy"
                                     ),
                  "results" => array ( 79,
                                       54,
                                       55,
                                       58,
                                       78,
                                       53,
                                       40,
                                       95,
                                       60,
                                       66
                                     ),
                    "grades" => array ( "1H",
                                       "2H2",
                                      "2H2",
                                       "2H2",
                                       "1H",
                                       "2H2",
                                       "Pass",
                                       "1H",
                                       "2H1",
                                       "2H1"
                                     ),
                );
```

Comment: In what language? C++, java, algorithmic?

Comment: like @AdelBoutros said what language? To me looks like php, look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255281/how-to-group-array-and-count-them

Comment: Sorry, yes, PHP.  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
 foreach(array_count_values($array['grades']) as $grade => $count){
     echo $grade.' achieved '.$count. ' times'.PHP_EOL;
 }
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I had been trying with if...elseif statements but that was not fruitful.