# Find most consecutively repeating value in array

Tags: php, arrays, counting

I have an array like this:

```
$origen = ["dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","bear","bear","alien","mouse"];
```

I need to find the value which has the most consecutive occurrences and the number of occurrences of that value.

Most consecutively repeating value is: `dog` (3 times)

I thought that it could be done with `array_count_values()`, but that also counts non-consecutive values.

Comment: @Nytrix `array_count_values` doesn't account for the "consecutive" part, does it?

Comment: What is the desired output for your input data? Do you need the value with most consecutive occurences or all values with consecutive occurences?

Comment: What if it were `array('dog', 'mouse', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat');` You would not expect to see a count for dog then?

Comment: @nerdlyist no only consecutive , for example this array : array('cat','cat','dog','dog','dog','bear','cat') , output : dog repited 3 times  consecutive.

Comment: Based on your comment to @Don'tPanic what you state there is not accurate. Are looking for the number of repetitions or number of occurrence of repetition?

Comment: number of occurrence of repetition.

Comment: Related page: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5255281/2943403

Answer (score 2):

`array_count_values` won't help you with this if keeping track of *consecutive* repetitions is important. You'll just have to loop over the array and compare each value to the previous value. If it matches, increment your "repeated" count for that word.

```
$origen = array("dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","bear","bear","alien","mouse");

$previous = null;
$repetitions = array();
foreach ($origen as $word) {
    if ($word == $previous) {
        if (!isset($repetitions[$word])) $repetitions[$word] = 1;
        $repetitions[$word]++;
    } 
    $previous = $word;
}
print_r($repetitions);
```

Output

```
Array ( [dog] => 3 [cat] => 2 [bear] => 2 )
```

---

Your comment was correct, the previous method only works if there is only one repeated set of any repeated words. If there can be more than one set (why now?) I came up with this:

First, separate the array of words into sub-arrays, separated by repeated sets.

```
$previous = null;
foreach ($origen as $word) {
    if ($word != $previous) {
        if (!empty($set)) $sets[] = $set;
        $set = [$word];
    } else {
        $set[] = $word;
    }
    $previous = $word;
}
if ($set) $sets[] = $set;
```

Then examine the sets and add up instances that have more than one item (consecutive repetitions of a word.)

```
foreach ($sets as $set) {
    if (count($set) > 1) {
        $key = reset($set);
        if (!isset($result[$key])) $result[$key] = 0;
        $result[$key] += count($set);
    }
}
```

Comment: no works in array like this :
$origen = array("dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","bear","dog","dog","mouse");

output
Array ( [dog] => 4 [cat] => 2 )

Comment: @Jean That's certainly true, and a good point. I think I see how that could be handled, though. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: thanks for the update , but the same resutl , output : Array ( [dog] => 5 [cat] => 2 )

Comment: Oh, I thought that's what it should be. What should it be?

Comment: Well, let's look at this array 
$array = array ("x","x","x","a","b","x","x","x","x","c","x","x","x","x","x")
The x is repeated 5 times consecutively.
that is the result

Comment: Oh, so the maximum of consecutive repetitions for each word?

Comment: I see. I'm not near a computer any more and can't write code well on my phone, but I'll make one more edit when I get back. Probably tomorrow, though.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `preg_match_all`, `array_combine` and `array_map` functions:

```
$origen = ["dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","bear","bear","alien","mouse"];
$reps = [];
if (preg_match_all("/(\w+) (\\1\s?){1,}/", implode(" ", $origen), $matches)) {
    $reps = array_combine($matches[1], array_map(function($v){
        return count(explode(' ', trim($v)));
    }, $matches[0]));
}

print_r($reps);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [dog] => 3
    [cat] => 2
    [bear] => 2
)
```

Comment: what if i need to use same for numbers? `$origen = [1,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,2];`

Comment: Then search Stack Overflow for duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5255281/2943403 and others

Comment: In its current form, this answer is not reliable. https://3v4l.org/BrSZm and `{1,}` is more simply written as `+`.

Answer (score -1):

I probably shouldn't be using session variables for this, but:

```
session_start();
session_unset();

$_SESSION["counts"] = Array();

function value_count($s) {
     if (!isset($_SESSION[$s])) {
        $_SESSION[$s] = 1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION[$s] += 1;
    }

    if (!in_array($s, $_SESSION["counts"])) {
        array_push($_SESSION["counts"], $s);
    }

}

$origen = Array("dog","dog","dog","cat","cat","bear","b   ear","alien","mouse");

foreach ($origen as $value) {
    value_count($value);
}

foreach ($_SESSION["counts"] as $item) {
    echo $item . ": " . $_SESSION[$item] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to misuse/abuse a session variable here to get data in/out of the function scope AND using `in_array()` is one of the least efficient tools that can be used for this task.