# How can I tell if a credit card is active?

Tags: api, credit-card

I know it's possible to [test if a card is valid with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315647/regex-credit-card-number-tests#23231321), but how would I test if a card is active and can be charged? I just tried to sign up for a free trial of a popular online streaming service with my old de-activated visa card and the number was valid, but still declined when I tried to move forward.

Is there some general way to test for this?

Whenever I google for this I get a lot of paypal tutorials, and I'd like to stay away from paypal if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate a credit card is legitimate:

1. Verify it against the [Luhn Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). (Will only validate the card number is in a valid format).
2. Verify the card number against known [Issuer Identification Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_number).
3. Perform an Authorization Only (aka AUTH ONLY) for $0.00 (or $0.01 if your processor does not support zero auths). This is the only guaranteed way to verify a credit card exists.