# Why is this regex pattern not passing in the exec method?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a card swipe and I am creating a on site Kioske and need to prefill a credit card form after card swipe. I am not sure why It is not recognizing any cards. Here is an example of a swipe:

```
%B5500005555555559"TORRANCEJACK G P        "2009206000000000000326000000
```

Can someone explain why it is not passing the following regex pattern exec?

```
// MasterCard starts with 51-55, and is 16 digits long.
var pattern = new RegExp("^%B(5[1-5][0-9]{14})\\^([A-Z ]+)/([A-Z ]+)\\^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})");
var match = pattern.exec(rawData);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, but this two tutorial help you a lot 


- [Regex](https://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/learn-regular-expressions-in-20-minutes)
-[Credit Card](https://tutorialzine.com/2016/11/simple-credit-card-validation-form)

Comment: One way to debug this would be to start with a much smaller regex (the beginning) and work your way toward the end and see when it breaks.

Comment: closer: `var pattern = /%B(5[1-5][0-9]{14})\"([A-Z ]+)([A-Z ]+)\"([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/` aside: use a literal, it's much easier to read than an escaped regexp string

Comment: @dandavis It is now validating and I agree it is better to read using a literal. I think I can work from your example. Thank you very much.

Comment: @dandavis why was it not validating with the provided regex from my example? I am using https://github.com/CarlRaymond/jquery.cardswipe btw

Comment: you had quote as caret and an extra slash

Comment: If you want a substantial answer, please explain what the expected result in `match` you expect. Certainly you *can work from the example* above,  but what good is a question that is not clear? It will be closed and eventually deleted.

Comment: Please check https://regex101.com/r/lQNKoq/1 and let know if you need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use the following pattern:

```
/%B(5[1-5][0-9]{14})"([A-Z ]+?)\s+"([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MeGIQi/1). Note you will have to fine tune the last `([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})` groups to get the right digits into the necessary number of groups.

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /%B(5[1-5][0-9]{14})"([A-Z ]+?)\s+"([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/g;
var s = '%B5500005555555559"TORRANCEJACK G P        "2009201800000000000326000000';
var matches = rx.exec(s);
if (matches) {
 console.log("Number: " + matches[1]); // => number
 console.log("Name: " + matches[2]); // => name
 console.log("Exp. year: " + matches[3]); // => exp year
 console.log("Exp. month: " + matches[4]); // => exp month
}
```

Comment: This works too, same as @dandavis - The last set of digits however are just to be used the first 4 digits which represent year (20) and month (09). The rest of the digits are to be discarded. It works great regardless, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it from here [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315647/regex-credit-card-number-tests)

```
^(?:5[1-5][0-9]\d{1}|222[1-9]|2[3-6][0-9]\d{1}|27[01][0-9]|2‌​720)([\ \-]?)\d{4}\1\d{4}\1\d{4}$
```

not sure about your regex working but says error to me on that slash `/`

Test this regex in [Regex Tester](https://regexr.com/) this is working

Also i found useful something from [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html)

If you need real program to prove working i make it for you if you need in snippet

Comment: This is not what I am trying to achieve. I have a hardware that reads from magnetic card as shown in the example and It brings the card number, cardholder name as well as the expiration date. I need to validate the regex provided. It needs to break the provided data in 3, card number, carholder name and expiration date.