# Regex Expression on 16-digit number

Tags: regex

I am stuck on this regex problem.

A 16-digit credit card number, with the first digit being a 5 and the second digit being a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 (the rest of the digits can be anything).

so far I have `^4[1,5]\d{14}` and I know I'm missing a lot of things but I dont know what I'm missing..

please help and thanks!

Comment: Check for a solution at [Regex credit card number tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315647/regex-credit-card-number-tests).

Comment: In regex `1,5` doesn't indicate a range but does `1-5`. You need `^4[1-5]\d{14}$`

Answer (score 2):

Look at the start of your regex:

```
^4[1,5]
```

That says that the number must start with 4 (not 5), and that the second character must be 1, a comma, or 5.

You want this instead (followed by the rest, of course):

```
^5[1-5]
```

Note the use of `-` rather than `,` to indicate a range of characters.

Answer (score 1):

The full regex you're looking for is the following

```
^5[1-5]\d{14}$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AH5wbX/1/)**

Your error lays in the fact that you used `1,5` as a range but this will just match `1` `,` or `5` as characters. To use a range, the `-` is needed between the enclosings