# Regular expression for Cirrus card type

Tags: regex, regex-negation, credit-card, regex-group

I need to get card type from card number. I've found these regex examples: [michaelkeevildown gist](https://gist.github.com/michaelkeevildown/9096cd3aac9029c4e6e05588448a8841), [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231321)

But [Cirrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirrus_(interbank_network)) card type isn't provided anywhere. Is there a possibility to distinguish cirrus from Maestro/Mastercard?

**UPD:**
In my case `^676623\d+$` was enough, but for different banks, the solution may differ.

Comment: Have you tried using a MasterCard regex against a Cirrus or Maestro card?  All three cards should fall under the same umbrella, at least [from a business point of view](https://brand.mastercard.com/brandcenter/more-about-our-brands.html).

Comment: I've found a card example image, where the card number looks like `6757****` that match neither Maestro `(5018|5020|5038|6304|6759|6761|6763)` nor Mastercard `5[1-5]`.