# how to validate field in angular reactive form?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to validate my form in angular using reactive form .There is few fields example `card name` in which user enter  only `string`

so he try to enter anything other than string I need to show invalid message .I tried like this

https://codesandbox.io/s/jzq6nn6zz9

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.paymentForm = this.fb.group({
      cardname: [
        "",
        [(Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+"))]
      ],
      cardnumber: [""],
      dateofexipiredate: [""],
      dateofexipireyear: [""],
      cvc: [""]
    });
  }
```

when I run my `application` my form is already valid why ?
[image]
it should only valid when user `enter string`

Comment: Instead of waiting for an answer (it's gonna be a long one so not many people want to spend time writing something that is already explained in detail in Angular guide), read up https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra brackets `()` in form `Validators` array. `Validators` should be sent as an array. After adding `()`, they are being treated as one single item, which is giving false results.

```
this.paymentForm = this.fb.group({
      cardname: [
        "",
        [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+")] // see this line
      ],
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syozbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: hi it is correctly work but why it is invalid when I type `a` or when I type `any charter` .after tying second character it show valid

Comment: Because of your validation `Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+")` which requires minimum of 2 characters

Comment: If you want only one, then you may do `Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z]+")`

Comment: can you please tell me one more thing how I will add pattern of `16` digit card number ..user only enter number in card number and which exact `16`

Comment: Check the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315647/regex-credit-card-number-tests That should help you.

Comment: Hi i don't want to validate card number .I want user only type number which have length 16

Comment: Ok, You are looking for some mask. This library should help you https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask You can modify according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Write 1 custom Validator for this task. I have added 1 sample here, just change your condition in the validator.

```js
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export function SameEmail(control: AbstractControl) {
    let email = window.localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (control.value == email) {
        return { validEmail : true };
    } else {
        return null;
    }
   
}


this.customForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'email': new FormControl(this.customForm.email, [
          Validators.required,
          SameEmail
        ])
      });
```

```html
<div *ngIf="form.email.invalid && (form.email.dirty || form.email.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="form.email.errors.required">
                Error 1
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="form.email.errors.validEmail">
                Error 2
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Validators.minLength(1)` sure he enter at least one character and `Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+")` will check if he enter valid name

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.paymentForm = this.fb.group({
      cardname: [
        "",
        [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+"),Validators.minLength(1)]
      ],
      cardnumber: [""],
      dateofexipiredate: [""],
      dateofexipireyear: [""],
      cvc: [""]
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use formGroup error checking to make sure it works properly. `yourForm.get('cardname').hasError('required')`
You can also check add some extra div in your HTML that will be displayed when user is doing something wrong in real time.
Here's example with checking if element is required:

```
<div *ngIf="yourFormGrup.get('cardname').hasError('required')">Card name is required.</div>
```

It will be visible only when your form group contains specified error. Here's some [extra reading for you](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) that should help You out.