# Replacing with javascript regex not working

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to use a regex to grab, and remove, credit card numbers. I have found the following regex and tested it :

```
^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[25][1-7][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$
```

It matches correctly using a regex evaluator (eg www.regexr.com).

When I try to insert it into my code, it does not work :

```
var daRex = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[25][1-7][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/
daText = "Testing REGEX 123 4387000500875798";
daText = daText.replace(daRex, '');
```

Printing daText just shows the original text.

What have I done wrongly here ?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not using a regex here, but a plain text replacement.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew question has been edited is not a duplicate of the link anymore (might still be a duplicate of another one)

Comment: You have `^` and `$` so the regex will ONLY match if the ENTIRE STRING is a credit card number and won't work if it's in the middle of other text.

Comment: @ben Still, a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758874/when-to-use-this-symbol-in-regex. And a typo, too.

Comment: I'd say it's a typographical error if not a dupe. Either way, it's not a very good question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315647/regex-credit-card-number-tests/#9315696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the proper regexp delimiter, the `/`.
You also need to remove the `^` and the `$` otherwise it match on the full line only.

Last but not least, 
you want
`replacedText = daText.replace(daRex, '');`
and not 
`daText = replacedText.replace(daRex, '');`

```js
var daRex = /(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|[25][1-7][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})/
daText = "Testing REGEX 123 4387000500875798";
replacedText = daText.replace(daRex, '');
console.log(replacedText)
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain all of my mistakes. I have now learned and improved as a result of your answer, and I appreciate that. Thanks again.