# Regex to support the 19 digit master card validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am using the following regex for master card. How i can change it to support 19 digit card and 16 digit as well Kindly help.

```
 masterCardPattern: /^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}$/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex credit card number tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315647/regex-credit-card-number-tests)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am looking for the 19 digit master card.

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer

```
^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)(?:[0-9]{3}){4,5}$
```