# Javascript I wrote isn't working for for my html

Tags: javascript, html

For my assignment, I have to create an online bookstore. I have created all the HTML and CSS needed. My only problem is the javascript. I have to create javascript code that will check the validity of the data inputted by the user.
Here is my code:

```
window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById("Pay Now").addEventListener("click", () => {
      const card = document.getElementById("card-number").value;
      const pattern = /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/;
      if (card.match(pattern)) {
        // If card number is valid, redirect to confirmation page
        window.location.href = "success.html";
      } else {
        // If card number is not valid, show an alert
        alert("Please enter a valid card number");
      }
    });
};
```

It's supposed to alert the customer if the number inputted isn't valid.

This is the HTML for the page it's supposed to link to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- Navigation Bar -->
        <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    <h1>Bookstore</h1>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src ="card.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Payment Details</h2>
    <form>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Name on Card</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
        <input type="number" id="card-number" name="card-number" required>
      </div>
      <label for="expiry-month">Expiry Date</label>
    <div class="expiry-date">
    <select id="expiry-month" name="expiry-month">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select id="expiry-year" name="expiry-year">
        <option value="">Year</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
        <option value="2023">2023</option>
        <option value="2024">2024</option>
        <option value="2025">2025</option>
        <option value="2026">2026</option>
    </select>
    </div>
      <div>
        <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
        <input type="number" id="cvv" name="cvv" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Pay Now</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please advise

Comment: It would be helpful to include what the actual problem is.

Comment: According to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id An id should not contain white spaces.

Comment: You don't have `id="Pay Now"` anywhere in the HTML. You also can't have a space in an ID.

Comment: your eventListener is missing its closure `});`

Comment: "Pay Now" is not a valid id. Add a real id to the button element. Also, don't forget to look at the browser's console when you're developing

Comment: The button you are trying to create an Event Handler on doesn't have an Id. "Pay Now" is its content not Id

Comment: And please include these error traces when you ask a question here

Comment: Do not use regex to check card validity. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55019607/4115245.

Comment: So you need to find a way to select the button. `document.querySelector("form button")` is one of many. Or just use a submit handler on the form.

Comment: Note that no page content can be in the [document head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head). That's invalid HTML.

Comment: There should be a proper selector on which you are adding the listener. There is no proper `id` for Pay Now button. Either add a proper id or query the button through different selector.

Comment: Also, html doesn't look good to me, navigation bar should not be there in head.

Comment: HI thank you, this really helped. The only problem i'm having is that when the card number is valid, it doesnt go onto the confirmation page. I dont know why it's not linking to it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If the issue is the event not firing, the problem is that you're writing
`document.getElementById("Pay Now")`
whereas your submit button has no id, 'Pay Now' is just the text of the button.
try adding id="pay-now" to the button.