# Create a dynamic "Free Shipping" Progress bar for Woocommerece widget in Wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use the Progress Bar plugin in wordpress to create a widget that shows a progress bar under the shopping cart of how much more they need to spend in order to get free shipping.

I need to first take the value of the cart:

```
global $woocommerce;
$price = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
```

Secondly Strip the dollar sign and round to nearest integer
?

Thirdly Output the value into the shortcode, so it displays properly into the HTML. As it is now, it outputs this for the width instead of a number.`<span class="red" style="width: .$cartnumber%;">`

I need this to output a plain number so it will work with the width. Below is the code so far.

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;
$total = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
$cartnumber = str_replace("&#36;", "", $total);
echo do_shortcode('[wppb progress='.$cartnumber.' option=red text="Free Shipping"]');
?>
```

I have enabled PHP execution within widgets for

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this before, and below is what I have used last.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Before I am using preg_match using [0-9\,\s.]+ pattern. Then I have replaced all special characters and letters to blank to get the integer. (not a good solution)

*Example code taken from http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm*

```
<?php 
    $ptn = "/[0-9\,\s\.]+/";
    $str = "$9,988,776.65 in the United States";
    preg_match($ptn, $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
 [0] => 9,988,776.65
)
```

After I realised that it was  not a good solution, I revised it to simpler solution using the code below. *from: [Remove non-numeric characters (except periods and commas) from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949279/remove-non-numeric-characters-plus-comma-and-period-from-a-string)*

```
$number = "$9,988,776.65";
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $number);
```

**Output**

```
998877665
```

if you did not remove the thousands and decimal symbol it will get the number format of the currency.

Regarding the progress bar, you need to convert the totals to 100%. I assume that your formula is similar below:

```
(price/free_shipping_minimum)*100
```

if result goes over 100 then set it to 100%. if you don't want decimals in your percentage cast it to int or use php's round/ceil/floor function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

I hope this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use

```
WC()->cart->subtotaĺ
```

Return a float, so no need to remove $ sign