# str_replace not doing what I need it to

Tags: php

I have a form that uses jQuery to calculate totals before submission. It sends the total along with the currency symbol to the form handling script. This is generating some

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

messages, so I have been using `str_replace`. However, the following code is still generating the errors. It works everywhere else apart from this one section of code and I cannot find a solution. Could anyone help with some advice.

```
function netprice() {
    $vatrate = 1.2;
    $gross = str_replace('£','',$_POST['unit_Price']);
    $net = round(($gross / $vatrate) , 2);

    if (empty($gross)) {
        echo"-";
    }else{
        echo $net;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `$_POST['unit_Price']` contain? `var_dump()` it and show us.

Comment: Hi Qirel. var_dump shows this string(0) ""

Comment: That means no corresponding `<input name="unit_Price">` (notice the case) is present in the form passed into PHP. Also, you should explicitly typecast the variable into an integer by using `intval()` to avoid future confusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't send the currency symbol with the form. If you cannot avoid it, there may be other characters such as a space between the symbol and the number.
First off you could try passing the resulting value through floatval() like such:

```
$gross = floatval(str_replace('£','',$_POST['unit_Price']));
```

If it still doesn't work, use regex instead to strip every character except for numbers, commas and dots:

```
$gross = floatval(preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/', '', $_POST['unit_Price']));
```

Comment: This is an important point. The currency shouldn't be dictated on the client-side.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks for that Pejka. And thanks to everyone for all your suggestions. Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You're welcome. As per Yaroslav Molchan's answer, you should also consider using filter_var() to get $_POST values instead of directly accessing it. Using raw form inputs can be a vulnerability.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again buddy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/function.filter-var.php) function to get only number from string.

```
$gross = filter_var($_POST['unit_Price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

If you want to get float use:

```
$gross = filter_var($_POST['unit_Price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
```

Comment: It's a good solution, but what if it is a float and not an integer?

Comment: This won't work as expected because price values can be float. For example `$gross = filter_var('£1.2', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);` will return (string)12

Comment: @Qirel add this to in answer

Comment: Cheers for this mate. I did not see your answer for float until it was too late, otherwise this would have been the answer I selected.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `str_replace`that could be leaving spaces or other chars, you could use `preg_replace`as in the example here [Remove non-numeric characters (except periods and commas) from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949279/remove-non-numeric-characters-exlcuding-periods-and-commas-from-a-string)

your code would look like this:

```
function netprice() {

$vatrate = 1.2;

$gross = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $_POST['unit_Price']);
$net = round(($gross / $vatrate) , 2);

    if (empty($gross)) {

        echo"-";

    }else{

        echo $net;
    }
}
```

`preg_replace` will strip out all chars except for those defined in the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Change `£` to `&#163;`

Also check your output, which data contains `$gross` after `str_replace`

Answer (score 0):

If your currency symbol is before the value, you can use a substr:

```
<?php
$price = substr('£1.2', 2); //1.2
```

> Note that because £ symbol is an special char you must substract 2 first chars. You can check it by doing a var_dump

If your currency symbol is at the end, you can simply force de value to be float:

```
$price = (float)'1.2£'; //1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help guys. I went with Pejka's solution

```
$gross = floatval(preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/', '', $_POST['unit_Price']));
```

I really appreciate all your help. A thousand thanks :)