# How to match some characters with a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I have string `"image(100)"`, i want filter the string to remove `image` and the parentheses then return just the number `100`.

i have tried `/[^image]/` and `image` removed, but i don't know how to remove `parenthesis`.

Comment: A character class is a listing of allowed/disallowed characters. It is not a series of characters. `[^image]` allows for a non `i`, `m`, `a`, `g`, or `e`. You could do `[^\d]+`, or just use PHPglue's answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove non-numeric characters (exlcuding periods and commas) from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949279/remove-non-numeric-characters-exlcuding-periods-and-commas-from-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape parentheses with a backslash, as they are special characters in regular expressions. Here I use them to [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the number and [save it to the `$matches` array](http://php.net/preg-match).

```
<?php
$str = "image(100)";
if (preg_match("/image\((\d+)\)/", $str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To just replace non-digits, with nothing, it's like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/\D/', '', 'image(100)');
```

Comment: I'd just quantify the `\D` so you twice rather than seven times (`\D+`).

Comment: Simpler than mine for sure, as long as there's no surrounding text.